# How to properly return inserted element in linked ilist

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

I'm implementing an insert (before an element) and add (after an element) functions for a doubly linked list. My question is the difference in the value I have to return and why they're different.

For my insert function `Link* insert(Link* n)`, I have to `return n`. For my add function `Link* add(Link* n)`, I have `return this`. I have tested what happens when I don't do this, the previous/subsequent elements don't show up. I'm wondering why that is, and why I can't `return n` (or `return this`) for both `insert`/`add`.

```cpp
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Link {
public:
   string value; 

   Link(const string& v, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
      : value{v}, prev{p}, succ{s} { }

   Link* insert(Link* n) ;   // insert n before this object
   Link* add(Link* n) ;      // insert n after this object
   Link* erase() ;           // remove this object from list
   Link* find(const string& s);    // find s in list
   const Link* find(const string& s) const; // find s in list

   Link* advance(int n) const;     // move n positions in list

   Link* next() const { return succ; }
   Link* previous() const { return prev; }

private:
   Link* prev;
   Link* succ;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Link* Link::insert(Link* n)   // insert n before this object; return n
{
   if (n == nullptr) return this;
   n->succ = this;          
   if (prev) prev->succ = n; 
   n->prev = prev;        
   prev = n;                 
   return n;   // why?           
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Link* Link::add(Link* n)   // insert n after this object
{
  if (n == nullptr) return this;
  n->prev = this;
  if (succ) succ->prev = n;
  n->succ = succ;      
  succ = n;      
  return this; // why?
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Link* Link::erase()
{
   if (succ) succ->prev = prev; // if (succ != nullptr)
   if (prev) prev->succ = succ;
   return succ;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Link* Link::find(const string& s) // find s in list;
// return 0 for "not found"
{
   Link* p = this;
   while(p) {
      if (p->value == s) return p;
      p = p->succ;
   }
   return 0;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void print_all(Link* p)
{
   cout << "{ ";
   while (p) {
      cout << p->value;
      if ( (p = p->next()) ) cout <<  ", ";
   }
   cout << " }";
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
   Link* norse_gods = new Link{"Thor"};
   norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Odin"});
   norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Zeus"});
   norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Freia"});

   Link* greek_gods = new Link{"Hera"};
   greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Athena"}); 
   greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Mars"});
   greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Poseidon"});

   Link* p = greek_gods->find("Mars");
   if (p) p->value = "Ares";

   // Move Zeus into his correct Pantheon: 
   {
      Link* p = norse_gods->find("Zeus");
      if (p) {
         if (p==norse_gods) norse_gods = p->next();
         p->erase();
         greek_gods = greek_gods->insert(p);
      }
   }

   // Finally, let's print out those lists:

   print_all(norse_gods);
   cout<<"\n";

   print_all(greek_gods);
   cout<<"\n";
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your `Link` class is acting as both the list itself and each node in the list.  You should separate the responsibilities, ie `Link` should just be the data storage for the `value`, and then create a `List` class that manages a list of `Link` instances.  All of your list operations (add, insert, erase, find, etc) should be moved to this new `List` class. Then `add()` and `insert()` can return the new `Link` node that was created.

Comment: @kino Ask this question to the person who wrote the code.:)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason of different return values of the functions insert and add is that when the function `insert` is applied to the node that represents the head node then the head node is changed and the new inserted node becomes the head node.

On the other hand, when a new node is added after the head node then the head node stays the same.

So the both functions return pointers to the head node.

If to consider this code snippet in mains

```
Link* norse_gods = new Link{"Thor"};
norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Odin"});
norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Zeus"});
norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{"Freia"});
```

then after these calls of the member function insert the head node is the node that contains the string `"Freia"`. That is these calls always insert a new node before the head node and the newly inserted mode becomes the head node.

In this code snippet in main

```
Link* greek_gods = new Link{"Hera"};
greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Athena"}); 
greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Mars"});
greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{"Poseidon"});
```

after these calls of the function add the head node is the node that contains the string `"Hera"`. That is new nodes are inserted after the head node. The pointer to the head node stays unchanged.

In the both cases in the function that outputs the list

```
void print_all(Link* p)
{
   cout << "{ ";
   while (p) {
      cout << p->value;
      if ( (p = p->next()) ) cout <<  ", ";
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   }
   cout << " }";
}
```

you can traverse it in the one forward direction using the data member `succ`

```
Link* next() const { return succ; }
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Would it be possible to modify both functions so that they can both return the same thing? This code is taken from Stroustrup's PPP.  Is it because, as @Remy Lebeau said, that I should allow for separation of responsibilities that this is happening?

Comment: @kino I described the logic behind the function. It is unclear why you want to break the logic.